# get nearest value to a cell value from a range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the nearest value of a range EXCLUDING the blank cells in a range. I have managed to get it done but it includes the blanks as they considered with zero's
this is the one that works that includes blanks

```
=INDEX(B9:GS9,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B9:GS9-D1)),ABS(B9:GS9-D1),0))
```

I've also tried to do MINIFS with criteria "<>" but it pops the error window. and also in addition to final solution, a VBA code of it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Related to the VBA side... you would need to take the initiative and attempt to code what you're looking for (Macro Recorder in Developer tab is a great starting tool).  Once you've got some base code and have a related, objective question we can give you feedback.  Since there are numerous ways to do this with VBA and this is not the appropriate forum to discuss the subjective nature of which is better, your question appears to be `Too Broad` and may be closed as such.

Comment: To the formula aspect of your request, can you display what you tried for `minifs`?  My first thought to keep it related to a formula is an if-statement using `minifs() - target < target - maxifs()`.

Answer (score 0):

keeping with formulas:

```
=IF((D1-MAXIFS(A:A,A:A,"<"&D1))<(MINIFS(A:A,A:A,">"&D1)-D1),MAXIFS(A:A,A:A,"<"&D1),MINIFS(A:A,A:A,">"&D1))
```

Where D1 is the Target value, then i breakdown and show the `MaxIf() < Target` and `MinIf() > Target`to show values and the Delta from Target.  Combined those formulas into the single formula above.

[image]

Note that this is based on a target value and is not using `>=` or `<=`, so if your target is 0, blanks wont' give values.

---

**Edit1:**

Fixed an error in the formula above where I accidentally listed D3 instead of D1 are the target value (didn't update image).

I've looked at this for an array; the formula is similar and would look like:

```
=IF((B11-MAXIFS(A1:H7,A1:H7,"<"&B11))<(MINIFS(A1:H7,A1:H7,">"&B11)-B11),MAXIFS(A1:H7,A1:H7,"<"&B11),MINIFS(A1:H7,A1:H7,">"&B11))
```

[image]

---

To look at this with your target range (`B9:GS9`) with the assumption that `D1` houses your target value:

```
=IF((D1-MAXIFS(B9:GS9,B9:GS9,"<"&D1))<(MINIFS(B9:GS9,B9:GS9,">"&D1)-D1),MAXIFS(B9:GS9,B9:GS9,"<"&D1),MINIFS(B9:GS9,B9:GS9,">"&D1))
```

In testing with your range, it looks like there's an error where there either is not a value > target or a value < target, resulting in a `0` for one of the results.  I used `CountIfs()` to get around that...

```
=IF((D1-If(CountIfs(B9:GS9,"<"&D1),MAXIFS(B9:GS9,B9:GS9,"<"&D1),D1))<(If(CountIfs(B9:GS9,">"&D1),MINIFS(B9:GS9,B9:GS9,">"&D1),2*D1)-D1),MAXIFS(B9:GS9,B9:GS9,"<"&D1),MINIFS(B9:GS9,B9:GS9,">"&D1))
```

Comment: My target value could be 0 as well, let's say I have values 5,13,95. and the target will be 0, the needed value to be returned would be 5.

Comment: @yon1000 that should be the case.  The blanks aren't values (blank = 0), so when you see what is > or < 0, it cannot be the blank items.  Let me know if this works for you, as I was testing it and it worked for me.

Comment: What the double A:A stands for, based on your photo, it seems to be missing a range of A1:A7. I've changed the all A:A  to B9:GS9, and it always returns 0.

Comment: @yon1000 See **Edit 1**

Comment: It partially works,it fails when entering a value that is lower than all the other values in the range, it returns 0. lets say the range is {8,4,3,5,12} and the target is 2.9, it returns 0 in that case while 3 would be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the recommendation here, It still returns a 0. here is a link for the image of the result.(It doesn't allow me to post images)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IRVa.png

Comment: I tried using `CountIfs()` which appears to work... not sure if your data has values less than 0 (not seeing any in your example).  I would probably recommend a user-defined function ("UDF") since it is a bit more reasonable to handle the data, ensuring you're excluding blanks.